# Regex: space + word

Tags: regex

I am a bit new in Regex.
Have an issue with one task.
Have to create regex that matches string like ' you' only (space and a word 'you').

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: So, you already have your regex.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2):

The regex would probably be `' you'`. You don't really need regex to check for that.

If you wanted to be clever about it and allow any kind of horizontal space then `'\hyou'`.

If you want to allow new lines before the word too then `'\syou'`.

Of course it depends what type of regex you're using as there is more than one type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try regular expression:

```
/^\s{1}you$/
```